# How to test for previously joined layers before run a code

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I've a function that join two added layers. The code works fine, but now I need to test for previously joined layers before run this function. The function code is right below:

```
def jointables(dict): # this dict provides [targetLayer:layerToJoin]
  for k, v in dict.items():
    target = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(k)
    layerToJoin = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(v)
    fieldToJoin = QgsProject.instance()
    symb = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
    symb.setJoinFieldName('id_feature')
    symb.setTargetFieldName('id')
    symb.setJoinLayerId(layerToJoin.id())
    symb.setEditable(True)
    symb.setDynamicFormEnabled(True)
    symb.setUpsertOnEdit(True)
    symb.setPrefix('')
    symb.setJoinLayer(layerToJoin)
    target.addJoin(symb)
```

I've tried some things like this:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    if QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(k).addJoin(QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()) == True:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

or

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    if QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo().isEditable() == True:
       break
    else:
       continue
```

among others. I've missing something. Both conditionals has the same value True, doesnt matter if already exists an previously joined layer or not. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do u use an **addJoin** in your first example ? Why do u use an **isEditable** in your second example ? What has that to do with joined layers ?

Comment: I'm new in pyqgis and this was a way find by me to test if there was a previously join, but its wrong. And answering your final question the intention is don't do another join if it already exists. My plugin is functioning but if I press 100 times the plugin button there will be a 100 joins, and the point is: must have only one.

Comment: No problem ... so ... has my answer been of any use ?

Comment: Yes it enlightened my way, but I've to test every layer individually. Now I've to figure out how to do it individually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a **QgsVectorLayer** has any join you can try the following :

```
VL.vectorJoins()
```

vectorJoins() returns a list of **QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo** for each join set on the VL layer.

So testing for example that `len(VL.vectorJoins())==0` means there is no join on the layer.